# Remove SWT TableEditor

Tags: java, swt, editor

I'm facing an issue with Java swt. In my RCP application I run a thread that clear a table every time I start it so it could display again elements from a list. The new list has been updated.

The problem is when I run the thread, `uploadInformationTab.removeAll()` or `uploadInformationtab.clearAll()`remove|clear all the items except the items where I've seted `TableEditor progressBarEditor=new TableEditor(uploadInformationTab)`and `TableEditor checkBoxEditor=new TableEditor(uploadInformationTab)`.

I can't find a solution to this issue.

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to dispose of any editor you have set when you set the new values in the table. Something like:

```
Control oldEditor = progressBarEditor.getEditor();
if (oldEditor != null) oldEditor.dispose();

oldEditor = checkBoxEditor.getEditor();
if (oldEditor != null) oldEditor.dispose();
```

Note: If this is an Eclipse RCP you could use the JFace `TableViewer` and `EditingSupport` which are a lot easier to use.

Update:

`Table.clearAll()` just clears the text and icons from all the rows in the table. It leaves the number of rows unchanged. `Table.removeAll()` sets the table to be empty, completely deleting all existing rows.

Comment: Ok I'll try this and let you know. I'll write this code in the run(){} ? And what is the best solution|difference between clear() and remove()?

Comment: Where to exactly put the dipose()? Right after the run() it returns NullPointerException and right after the creation of the editor never the display it.

Comment: Now, I have this error : `Widget is dispose`. I use the progressbar to show the upload progression of a file. So I have a listener that paint the progress bar... For one file, the dispose is working good, but when files, it returns :  `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed`